# The connection of Faltings height and Tate module

Tags: diophantine-equations, diophantine-approximation, diophantine-geometry, heights

Suppose $K$ is a number field, $S$ a finite set of places of $K$, and $A$ is an abelian scheme over $\mathcal O_{K,S}$. I want to ask is there some connections between the Faltings' height $h_F(A)$ and the Tate module of $A$ as a Galois representation?

Since effective Shafarevich conjecture means there is an effective bound for the Faltings' height, I wonder if this statement can be translated to a statement of Tate modules.